# MenuItem Click event handler not called

Tags: c#, .net

I´m building a ContextMenu on the fly, like this

```
            readinstance = null;
            ContextMenu cMenu = new ContextMenu();
            for (int i = 0; i < instances.Length; i++) {
                string text = String.Format("{0} - {1}", instances[i].Id, instances[i].FormName);
                MenuItem item = new MenuItem(text, new EventHandler(cMenuitem_Click));
                item.Tag = instances[i];
                cMenu.MenuItems.Add(item);
            }
            cMenu.Show((Button)sender, new Point(0, 0));
            cMenu.Dispose();
            if (readinstance == null)
                throw new Exception("Must select some instance");
```

and the handler is

```
    void cMenuitem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MenuItem item = (MenuItem)sender;
        readinstance = (FormPrintingStorage)item.Tag;
    }
```

The menu displays correctly, but when I click some of the options, the handler is not called, so readinstance remains null, and the exception throws. As a side note, when I click any of the options, the menu disappears.
I cannot see what is wrong with my code. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I´m answering my own question, because I tried more ways. 
The first one was to replace the ContextMenu with a ListView and an "Ok" button, at no luck, because the wait loop needed a Thread.Sleep. No comments.

The solution was to implement a new dialog with an empty list view an the Ok button. Some of the relevant code follows. Note that only TreeViewItem/s are moved between the main form and the dialog.

```
    ListViewItem _result = null;

    public ListViewItem Result { get { return _result; } }

    public List<ListViewItem> Source
    {
        set
        {
            listView1.Items.Clear();
            foreach (ListViewItem item in value)
                listView1.Items.Add(item);
            listView1.View = View.List;
        }
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (_result == null)
            return;
        DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        Close();
    }

    private void listView1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ListView list = (ListView)sender;
        ListView.SelectedIndexCollection indices = list.SelectedIndices;
        if (indices.Count == 0)
            return;
        _result = list.Items[indices[0]];

    }
```

Getting the Result, the main form may do anything it wants with the Tag member. In fact, I´m using the same dialog for two different purposes in the same form.